# How does microphone -> software work?

Tags: audio-engineering

I've read this:

"A microphone converts sound into a small electrical current. Sound waves hit a diaphragm that vibrates, moving a magnet near a coil. In some designs, the coil moves within a magnet. Other microphones, such as condenser microphones, work on the principle of capacitance."

And I get how that converts sound to current. I've also read that speakers work by converting this current back into vibrations which then cause sound waves.

Here is what I am confused about: consider something like Siri, where a microphone interfaces directly with software. How does Siri/etc convert the current from the microphone to sound wave data (i.e a .mp3 file)? Is this just a shift/scale from the current waves? How are those factors calculated. I'm not confused on what Siri does with the sound wave data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is the essentially the same with the following:

**How does the output of a microphone (an analog device) gets transformed to digital data that a computer (a digital device) can process?**

The answer is through an [ADC chip (analog to digital converter)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter).

Which essentially does the following:

[image]

- it samples the analog system for a small dt
- it corresponds the mean value/integral of the analog system to a integer level (see 8 bit:[ 0-255], 10 bit:[ 0-1024] , 12 bit audio:[ 0-4096 ])

That data are now available for processing from the digital system.

Answer (score 0):

A chip converts the current signal to a digital format and the output mp3 or whatever is set by the software.

There may be other layers involved, such as if it is an external mic on a dedicated port or on usb etc